# Laravel transaction return null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am trying to query with db transaction .When my method run that time data inserted correctly in corresponding table.but it return null.

My Code

```
    return $result = DB::transaction(function() use ($attributes) {
        $service = $this->service->create($attributes);
        $visibilityAttributes = $attributes['dropdown_option_id'];
        $visibilityAttributes = array_map('intval', $visibilityAttributes);
        $service->visibility()->sync($visibilityAttributes);
    },3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DB::transaction()` returns whatever the closure passed into it returns. Since your closure doesn't return anything, `DB::transaction()` will return `null`. You need to add a `return` statement to your closure.

```
return $result = DB::transaction(function() use ($attributes) {
    $service = $this->service->create($attributes);

    $visibilityAttributes = $attributes['dropdown_option_id'];
    $visibilityAttributes = array_map('intval', $visibilityAttributes);
    $service->visibility()->sync($visibilityAttributes);

    // This value will be returned from DB::transaction().
    return $service;
},3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want to return any value then try below code:

```
$result = DB::transaction(function() use ($attributes) {
    $service = $this->service->create($attributes);
    $visibilityAttributes = $attributes['dropdown_option_id'];
    $visibilityAttributes = array_map('intval', $visibilityAttributes);
    $service->visibility()->sync($visibilityAttributes);
    return $service;
},3);
return $result
```

Comment: Why assign `$result` variable when you're just returning the closure return?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below by returning value oustide function.

```
 $result = DB::transaction(function() use ($attributes) {
        $service = $this->service->create($attributes);
        $visibilityAttributes = $attributes['dropdown_option_id'];
        $visibilityAttributes = array_map('intval', $visibilityAttributes);
        $service->visibility()->sync($visibilityAttributes);
    },3);

return $result;
```